# VBA code to toggle between two font colors (or cases) based on current font color

Tags: excel, vba, fonts, colors, case

I am trying to write a macro that will allow me to toggle between font colors.  To keep this simple, let just say two font colors.  From Black to Blue or Blue to Black.

However, I would like excel to tell my macro whether it is has selected black or blue font (either in the current cell or just in general).  And from there, determine which color to change to.

So, if the font color select on the toolbar is black, it will run change the font to blue (by running the appropriate portion of the below script).  And if the font color select on the toolbar is blue, it will run change the font to black (by running the appropriate portion of the below script as well).

Below, I have the code for the changing the fonts colors into blue or black.
The problem here is I do not know the proper syntax or code to have excel determine the currently selected font color on the toolbar (or cell, if doing this on the toolbar is not possible).  Determining the font color is the first part of the macro which is what I am having trouble with.

Appreciate the help!

```
Sub toggle()

'need code to determine font color, then to execute appropriate code below
With Selection.font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Exit Sub
blackpath:

With Selection.font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `if Selection.font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1 then` ...?

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the help.  Your if-then statement definitely does the trick.  However, I just notice that by trying to simplify my problem to be more easily understood, and hence framing this into a 2-case problem (black or blue) strips away some of the other problems.  Is there a way to determine the font color select on the toolbar ?(and not the active cell itself, I am beginning to believe this is not doable.)

Comment: so, you want to know what a user has selected currently for the font color, and not just what is in the current selection?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  That is part of the larger problem I am looking to solve.  How do I determine the font color (to start, or other properties) that is selected on the toolbar (and not necessary on any particular selected cell)?  I am really beginning to think this is not really doable in vba because vba simply applies or extracts an object or property, and the toolbar is more of a menu that applies a selected color.  (if that makes sense.)

Answer (score 1):

Following on from @SeanC:

```
Sub toggle()

    With Selection.font
        If .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1 Then
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
            .TintAndShade = 0
        ElseIf .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1 Then
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, your method and SeanC's both do the trick.  I was actually working on a slightly larger issue with more than one case, and overlooked how using if-then statements to form a lengthier algo can help.  Thanks again!

Comment: Is there a way to determine the font color selected on the toolbar ? (and not the active cell itself, I am beginning to believe this is not doable.)

Comment: No I don't think there's an easy way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

here is a way to find out which color is selected in the button

it is a kludge though

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim aaa As Long
    Dim fontColorButton As Long

    aaa = Range("a1").Font.Color

    Range("a1").Select
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("FontColorPicker")  ' click the "font color" button
                                                            ' get the command name from the "customize ribbon" dialog
    fontColorButton = Range("a1").Font.Color
    Range("a1").Font.Color = aaa

    Debug.Print fontColorButton

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice.  Maybe pick an empty cell to do that though: there's a slight risk there's mixed font color formatting in A1...

Comment: note: if you pick a cell way off to right or way down, it will affect the `Range.UsedRange` attribute in a possibly undesirable way (i forget the exact attribute name)

Comment: Thank you, the above works.  I was able to use parts of your above code to resolve this error that keeps coming up, and continue working.

Comment: what error are you talking about?  please add the description to your question. it is important for future reference

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of would be a horrible kludge:  use `Workbook_SheetChange` to get the current font color.

```
Option Explicit

Dim CurCol As Long ' default is: -16776961 you could set this on Workbook_Open

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    CurCol = Target.Font.Color
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and suggestions!